# "Same" Operator on Different Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Let $T$ be an operator acting on two Banach spaces $B_1$ and $B_2$ with the same expression. Assume as sets $B_1\subset B_2$, but the natural embedding $B_1\hookrightarrow B_2$ is not continuous with respect to the norm-topologies. For convenience, we write $T_1$ and $T_2$ for the two different actions of $T$.

I wonder if there are any theorems which deal with the relations between $T_1$ and $T_2$, for example, is there any relations between the spectrum of these two operators?

As I can see, for example, the point spectrum of $T_1$ is a subset of the point spectrum of $T_2$, as the existence of eigenvalues does not depend on the topology on $B_1$. But what else can we get?

Comment: My functional analysis is quite rusty, but, since $B_1$ is complete, isn't $B_1\times B_1$ a closed set in $B_1\times B_2$? This would imply that the natural embedding is continuous.

Comment: When you say "closed", with which topology are you saying that? Because the topologies of $B_1$ and $B_2|_{B_1}$ are different. @ajotatxe